# What is needed to protect long-distance minecart lines?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When building a minecart rail through multiple overworld biomes, what do I need to do to stop mobs from blocking the track?

The track will have tunnels, raised tracks, and tracks on the ground at various points. How do I stop spiders, etc from climbing or spawning on my tracks, especially when an above ground track goes into a tunnel?

Comment: Carrying a powerful bow with you while riding?

Comment: Normally mobs don't walk over the rails unless pushed by other mobs.

Answer (score 2):

The only truly foolproof methods for a safe area out in the open are:

1. A running water moat (ie dig a 1x4 ditch each side and fill the closest block of each moat with water)
2. Or a 2-high wall with an overhang, on each side of the track, with the track section lit. Fencing or glass will give a better view, but are more resource (in-game, not PC) heavy.

In a tunnel, light the inside well and construct minecart doors at each end using activator rails and pistons

Answer (score 1):

Something that will help protect from all mobs are cacti. With Cacti scattered throughout the area you can make a x2 wall so that zombies and skeletons can't climb the cacti (If they pass it).

Place the cacti like so: C is cacti X is blank sand.

CXCXCXCXCXCXCX

For tunnels I would just put torches. If you don't have the materials for that, Placing water like a moat around the tracks would prevent the spawning and climbing of the mobs. Use the moat like this: W is water, X is air, T is track, C is a block of cobble stone.

> X-X-TX-X
>   WWCWW

Comment: Fences wouldn't work? Farming that many cacti would take a ton of effort and would obscure the view when they grew.

Comment: @Philip spiders can climb over fences.